# Why Jekyll's Liquid 'contains' returns a string?

Tags: jekyll, contains, liquid

I try to assign to a variable a `true` or `false` value depending on whether a string contains another string. I use the following code:

```
{% assign external_link = link.href contains '://' %}
```

For this snippet the `external_link`'s value will be the same as the `link.href`'s value (I checked the value of the `external_link` with the command `{{ external_link }}`).

I will get the same result even if I put parenthesizes around the right side:

```
{% assign external_link = (link.href contains '://') %}
```

What is the problem, and how can I get a `true`/`false` result of the `contains` expression?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [capture](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/variable-tags#capture) filter tag to get the result of the `contains` tag:

```
{% assign link = "http://example.com "%}
{% capture has_link %}{% if link contains '://' %}Yes{% else %}No{% endif %}{% endcapture%}
{{has_link}}

{% assign link = "example.com "%}
{% capture has_link %}{% if link contains '://' %}Yes{% else %}No{% endif %}{% endcapture%}
{{has_link}}
```

## Another option without `capture`

```
{% assign link = "http://example.com "%}
{% if link contains '://' %}
{% assign has_link = "yes" %}
{% else %}
{% assign has_link = "no" %}
{% endif %}
{{has_link}}

{% assign link = "example.com "%}
{% if link contains '://' %}
{% assign has_link = "yes" %}
{% else %}
{% assign has_link = "no" %}
{% endif %}
{{has_link}}
```

Output:

```
yes

no
```